# sort() error even when including <algorithm>

Tags: c++

I have also copied the exact code from Programming Principles & Practice but to no avail.
I get an error message when I try to use `std::sort(word)` or `sort(word)`:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:13:14: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)'
   13 |     std::sort(words);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
[...]
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    for(std::string temp; std::cin >> temp;){
        words.push_back(temp);
    }
    std::cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << "\n";

    std::sort(words);

     for(int i=0; i < words.size(); i++){
        if(i == 0; words[i-1]!=words[i]){
            std::cout << words[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that error `no match for ‘operator<<’` has anything to do with sort?

Comment: `words` vs `words.size()`; error message doesn't match the code.

Comment: sorry, this is my second day learning C++ but i thought it had something to do with calling sort() because using `std::` with `cout` works but not with sort

Comment: std::sort(words.begin(), words.end())

Comment: `std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());` got rid of the error message, thanks! I wish it was included in the book though

Comment: @SILO If your book actually instructed you to call `std::sort(words)`, get a better book. ;-)

Comment: @SILO please next time use [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/fjPfTq8M8) which will reproduce your issue. Note that you made other errors when posting a question (see comments above).

Comment: "std::sort(words.begin(), words.end()); got rid of the error message," ? do you mean the other error, the one you didnt include in the question? The one you included is not from the code you posted

Comment: i replaced the error message with the one I got here: https://godbolt.org/z/fsq1oM5dd.

Comment: @SILO you need to read [`std::sort` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Which book are you using? Try the good ones in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714)

Comment: You claim you copied that code from _Programming Principles and Practice using C++_ by Stroustrup?  I don't believe you, but maybe you misunderstood something.

Comment: @DevSolar The book OP appears to be using is written by Bjarne Stroustrup. OP’s error is not mentioned [in the errata](https://www.stroustrup.com/PPPslides/PPP2errata.html) so I think it’s more likely that OP is mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. your usage of `sort` is wrong, it's `std::sort(words.begin(), words.end())`. This should be in your book or in your learning material.
2. in `if (i == 0; words[i-1]!=words[i])` during the first iteration `i` is 0 and therefore you are accessing `words[-1]` which is out of bounds and which will at best trigger some error message. Also the `;` makes no sense here.

You probably want this:

```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (words[i] != words[i + 1]) {
      std::cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

sort function accepts either 2 or 3 variables. first 2 are for starting and ending indexes. In this case, they are words.begin() and words.end()

So, your 13th line (which has the error) should be:

```
std::sort(words.begin(),words.end());
```

The 3rd argument can be given to specify type of sort. For example,

```
std::sort(words.begin(),words.end(),greater<int>());
```

will sort the vector in reverse order.

Comment: `std::sort` accepts _iterators_, not indices